# Clarification on ADC protection circuit

Tags: diodes, tvs

Below is the circuit from one of the EVK reference designs and I would like to know the use/working of D6 TVS diode which is mounted in ADC circuit. Please provide the inputs.

[image]

Comment: D6 is a dual schottky diode. It is arranged as a clamp circuit. You havent asked a concise question, so we have no idea of the inputs you require.

Comment: @Kartman By "Inputs" he probably means provide him with input i.e. thoughts & ideas, not literal electrical signals

Comment: @kartman Analog_IN2 will vary from 0-36V, So ADC4 will get a voltage between 0-3.3V. How the clamp circuit will work with these voltages?

Comment: R115 and R118 form a 1:11 voltage divider. 36V will get divided down to 3.27V. If the divided voltage rises above the 3.3V rail by one diode drop, the left diode in D6 will be forward biased and clamp the input to just above the 3.3V rail. Similarly if the divided voltage drops below gnd, the right diode in D6 will conduct and clamp the input.